# Custom webservice test Class

Tags: apex, soap-api, webservices, soap

I develop a custom webservice may i know how can write a test class for below class
can anyone provide me some sample code for test class.

```
global class Main{

    global class RequestClass{
        webservice String errorMessage;


    global class Account{    
        webservice String accName;
        webservice String accNumber;     
    }

    global class ResponseClass{
        webservice String errorMessage;
        webservice String resId;
        webservice String resName;     
    }  

    webservice static ResponseClass behaviourOfWebService(RequestClass req){


                 a = new Account();

            a.Name = accName;
            a.AccountNumber =accNumber;   
            accountList.add(a);     
        }
        try{
            upsert AccountList;
        } catch(Exception e){
            Database.rollback(sp);
            return res;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sathya: there are many guides for writing test classes available. What is your specific problem?

Comment: @Mike Can you give me some sample for my webservice i am first time working with integration.

Comment: Here's one resource: http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods You can also just search for something like "salesforce apex unit testing" and find lots of explanatory posts.

Answer (score 2):

> For the service itself:

I think you can just invoke the static method:

```
@isTest public class MainTest {

    static testMethod void coverMain() {
        Blob data = Main.behaviourOfWebService('');
        System.assert(...);
    }

}
```

> For the client:

Salesforce have a [special mock implementation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_interface_webservicemock.htm) you can [inject](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex_testing.htm) as part of your unit test. Here's a basic implementation of `WebServiceMock` that maps to your question:

```
@isTest public class MainClientTest {

    class MainClientMock implements WebServiceMock {
        public void doInvoke(
            Object stub,
            Object request,
            Map<String, Object> response,
            String endpoint,
            String soapAction,
            String requestName,
            String responseNS,
            String responseName,
            String responseType
        ) {
            MainClient.Response responseElement = new MainClient.Response();
            responseElement.result = 'herpderp';
            response.put('response_x', responseElement);
        }
    }

    static testMethod void coverMainClient() {
        // This causes a fake response to be generated
        Test.setMock(WebServiceMock.class, new MainClientMock());

        MainClient.Client client = new MainClient.Client('');
        String result = client.behaviourOfWebService('');

        System.assert(result.startsWith('herpderp'));
    }

}
```

Comment: I think your  test class is we use when we convert wsdl to apex case.

Comment: can you give me the code based upon the my weebservice.

Comment: @User32o Can you please give me the sample test class based upon the 'For the service itself:' in this format.